# Android Layout - how to restrain textfield in size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myapp.ViewActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/myText" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/textfield"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/but"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:inputType="text"/>  
<Button
 android:id="@+id/but"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/suchen"
 android:layout_below="@+id/tex"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:onClick="search" />
<ListView
android:id="@+id/v"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textfield">    
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

however, the EditText is so big that the Listview is not even on the screen.
I have tried around to change that, but to no avail.
Is there a trick?

Second, is there a way to avoid having the name of the activity show up on the screen as title?

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

set the height of EditText to "wrap_content"  and in AndroidMenifest.xml in your activity declaration do this to hide the title:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

......

Comment: I tried that already but if I use wrap_content and the user happens to write a text which is longer than 1 line then the EditText adapts - which I clearly do NOT want.

Comment: if you want the EditText to be single line then: android:singleLine="true" , if you want it to be of fixed height then set height like android:layout_height="20dp" and wrap it with  <ScrollView > </ScrollView >

Answer (score 1):

You can add Theme.Black.NoTitleBar Theme if you want to hide title from all the screen in the application.

```
 <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >


    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your edittext, you have kept the height as match parent and hence its occupying the entire screen, you will have to change it to wrap_content.
To display the edittext and button next to each other wrap them in a layout.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText
android:id="@+id/textfield"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:inputType="text"/>  
<Button
android:id="@+id/but"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="@string/suchen"
android:onClick="search" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But the parent is a button - should  it not then match the height of this button?

Comment: besides if I do that I get an error: match_content not allowed for layout_height

Comment: Sorry its wrap_content..try this

Comment: Parent is not a button in this case,its relativelayout.

Comment: Tried. As in the edit. However, as I apprehended, NOW the textfield size adapts to the user input (which it should not) and it is still BELOW the button not next to it. Cannot I have both in one line?

Comment: Yes thats possible, i have updated my answer to show edittext and button next to each other. Add the above code instead of edittext and button code.

Comment: However, found another solution. Does not look as pretty but does what is necessary